# Tkinter flush buttons next to each other

Tags: python, tkinter

This has been asked before but I cant seem to figure out how to use the previous answers for my solution as it isn't working. I want to get 2 buttons flushed to the north west, and one RUN button flushed at the south west.

However, I get but buttons very spaced out, possibly because of the row size of the text field beside it. How do I fix this? I've attached current result as well as intended outcome

**Code Result**

[image]

**Intended Outcome**

Bad photo edit, the run button is supposed to be 2x bigger than the other buttons
[image]

**Current Code**

```
from tkinter import scrolledtext
import sys
from tkinter import filedialog
import tkinter
import datetime

class MyApp(object):
    """"""
    #----------------------------------------------------------------------
    def __init__(self, parent):
        """Constructor"""
        self.root = parent
        self.root.title("test program")

        self.frame = tkinter.Frame(parent)
        #self.frame.pack()

        self.frame.grid(column=0,row=0)
        enforcement_btn = tkinter.Button(self.frame, 
                             text="File 1")
        icare_btn = tkinter.Button(self.frame, 
                             text="File 2")
        run_btn = tkinter.Button(self.frame, 
                             text="RUN")

        enforcement_btn.grid(column=1,row=0, sticky='NW')
        icare_btn.grid(column=1,row=1, sticky='NW')
        run_btn.grid(column=1,row=2,sticky='SW')

        self.text = scrolledtext.ScrolledText(self.frame)
        self.text.grid(column=2,row=0,sticky='WENS',columnspan=2,rowspan=2)
        self.init_text()
    #----------------------------------------------------------------------

    def init_text(self):
        print("Console Test")

#----------------------------------------------------------------------
if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tkinter.Tk()
    root.geometry("600x300")
    app = MyApp(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

All help is much appreciated, thank you! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. make row 2 to expand:

   ```
   self.frame.rowconfigure(2, weight=1)
   ```
2. change `rowspan` of `self.text` from 2 to 3:

   ```
   self.text.grid(column=2, row=0, sticky='WENS', columnspan=2, rowspan=3)
   ```

Comment: thanks so much! Almost there, the run button seems to take up only half of the allotted area width wise, how would i max it? Columnspan doesnt seem to work

Comment: Change `anchor='SW'` to `anchor='SWE'`.